# excel_reader2 Abort

Tags: php, excel, abort

did anyone encountered a problem with excel_reader2, that the script got aborted by a big amount of rows, for example over 60k rows in the excel file? I just get an error message in error log : Aborted. Thats all. I got more files on my server and the script takes them 1 by 1 but when i get to the second the the message comes and script stops. Its php 5.4.7 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the problem, but phpexcel does not really like large excel files, that may be a problem. Please try to limit the data with reading only chunks, it may help.

Comment: iv got a test running right now, i imported a 500 ,1.6k and  a 60k row excel file, i will see if thats the root of the problem, if yes i switch to phpexcel.Edit: oh didnt read it to the end. So you say phpexcel reader got that issue.. hmm

Comment: Any PHP script that uses memory to load in a file will be subject to PHP memory limits. Note that PHPExcel provides a cell caching mechanism to reduce the affects of these limits by allowing cell data to be cached to disk, APC, memcache, even SQlite rather than loaded fully into memory